Merge timeseries dataframes of different lengths and time intervals
I wish to join two dataframes of different lengths and time intevals based on common variable DateTime15 so that the Hourly_Rainfall_mm in df2 is merged to the df1 where the DateTime15 matches, which is every hour.
df1<-structure(list(Tag = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Date = structure(c(1721174400, 
1721174400, 1721174400, 1721174400, 1721174400, 1721174400, 1721174400, 
1721174400, 1721174400, 1721174400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Time = structure(c(46820, 47764, 48665, 49566, 
50468, 51368, 52269, 53170, 54071, 54972), class = c("hms", "difftime"
), units = "secs"), Temp = c(17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.8, 17.8, 17.8, 
17.8, 17.7, 17.7, 17.7), `Baro (mb)` = c(1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 
1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016), pH = c(8.45, 8.42, 8.4, 
8.38, 8.38, 8.37, 8.37, 8.36, 8.36, 8.37), pHmV = c(-68.3, -67.1, 
-66.2, -65.2, -65, -64.8, -64.7, -64.4, -64.3, -64.5), `ORP (REDOX)` = c(225.8, 
212.5, 221.1, 229.1, 234, 237.5, 239.6, 240.6, 242.3, 242.6), 
    DO_Sat = c(107.4, 107.4, 106.6, 106.1, 106.3, 106.4, 106.5, 
    106.4, 106.7, 106.6), DO_mgL = c(10.16, 10.16, 10.08, 10.06, 
    10.08, 10.09, 10.09, 10.11, 10.14, 10.13), Conductivity = c(563, 
    561, 562, 561, 563, 560, 564, 564, 564, 565), `RES (Ohms.cm)` = c(2053, 
    2061, 2057, 2066, 2057, 2070, 2053, 2057, 2057, 2053), `TDS (mg/L)` = c(365, 
    364, 365, 364, 365, 364, 366, 366, 366, 367), `SAL (ppt)` = c(0.24, 
    0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.23, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24), `SSG (st)` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), NH3 = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
    0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01), cDOM = c(8.9, 8.9, 9.1, 
    9, 7.9, 8.7, 9.2, 8.7, 8.6, 8.9), Ammonium = c(0.13, 0.13, 
    0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.12), DateTime = structure(c(1721217620, 
    1721218564, 1721219465, 1721220366, 1721221268, 1721222168, 
    1721223069, 1721223970, 1721224871, 1721225772), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), DateTime15 = structure(c(1721217600, 
    1721218500, 1721219400, 1721220300, 1721221200, 1721222100, 
    1721223000, 1721223900, 1721224800, 1721225700), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

df2<-structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1721221200.055, 1721224800.06, 
1721228400.065, 1721232000.07, 1721235600.075, 1721239200.08, 
1721242800.085, 1721246400.09, 1721250000.095, 1721253600.1), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Hourly_Rainfall_mm = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 
1.4, 1.1), DateTime15 = structure(c(1721221200.055, 1721224800.06, 
1721228400.065, 1721232000.07, 1721235600.075, 1721239200.08, 
1721242800.085, 1721246400.09, 1721250000.095, 1721253600.1), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

I've spent hours going through stackoverflow questions trying to find a solution and have applied code from a number of answers but I seem to be missing something as none of them have worked for my dataframes.
JoinedDF<-left_join(df1, df2, by="DateTime15") # Returns all NA for Hourly_Rainfall_mm

JoinedDF<- merge(df1, df2, by.x = df1$DateTime15, 
                                             by.y= df2$DateTime15, all=TRUE) # gives error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns

JoinedDF<-merge(df1, df2, by="DateTime15", all=TRUE) # inserts an additional row in the dataframe 

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Your results are not reproducible. The first join works ok, 10 records are returned. The second and third ones do a full join (20 records), if you put by="DateTime15" for the "by.x" and "by.y" arguments in the second command.

Compare df1$DateTime15 |> dput() with df2$DateTime15 |> dput(): in df1 your datetimes are aligned to seconds (and in fact to hours), while in df2 you have fractional seconds.
(... Each measure being 1 hour + 1/200th of second [3600.005 seconds] after the preceding one. Presumably some earlier step in your process created those misalignments inadvertently.)
We can join df1 to df2 with rounded seconds in DateTime15:
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
df1 |>
  left_join(df2 |> mutate(across(DateTime15, ~round_date(., "second"))), 
            join_by(DateTime15))\

Selecting just cols 1:5 and Hourly_Rainfall_mm:
   Tag       Date     Time Temp Baro (mb) Hourly_Rainfall_mm
1    1 2024-07-17 13:00:20 17.9      1016                 NA
2    2 2024-07-17 13:16:04 17.9      1016                 NA
3    3 2024-07-17 13:31:05 17.9      1016                 NA
4    4 2024-07-17 13:46:06 17.8      1016                 NA
5    5 2024-07-17 14:01:08 17.8      1016                  0
6    6 2024-07-17 14:16:08 17.8      1016                 NA
7    7 2024-07-17 14:31:09 17.8      1016                 NA
8    8 2024-07-17 14:46:10 17.7      1016                 NA
9    9 2024-07-17 15:01:11 17.7      1016                  0
10  10 2024-07-17 15:16:12 17.7      1016                 NA


That worked perfectly, thanks so much

You should usehow='left' to ensure that all rows from df1 are included, and rows from df2 are matched based on DateTime15.
And Hourly_Rainfall_mm is showing as NaN because the DateTime15 values in df1 and df2 do not exactly match. Small differences in the datetime values, even by milliseconds, can cause the merge to fail. So I rounded the DateTime15 values to the nearest hour.
[![Hourly_Rainfall_mm][1]][1]
could you please try this code?

import pandas as pd

# Define df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Tag': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2024-07-15'] * 10, utc=True),
    'Time': pd.to_timedelta(['13:00:20', '13:16:04', '13:31:05', '13:46:06', '14:01:08', '14:16:08', '14:31:09', '14:46:10', '15:01:11', '15:16:12']),
    'Temp': [17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.8, 17.8, 17.8, 17.8, 17.7, 17.7, 17.7],
    'Baro (mb)': [1016] * 10,
    'pH': [8.45, 8.42, 8.4, 8.38, 8.38, 8.37, 8.37, 8.36, 8.36, 8.37],
    'pHmV': [-68.3, -67.1, -66.2, -65.2, -65, -64.8, -64.7, -64.4, -64.3, -64.5],
    'ORP (REDOX)': [225.8, 212.5, 221.1, 229.1, 234, 237.5, 239.6, 240.6, 242.3, 242.6],
    'DO_Sat': [107.4, 107.4, 106.6, 106.1, 106.3, 106.4, 106.5, 106.4, 106.7, 106.6],
    'DO_mgL': [10.16, 10.16, 10.08, 10.06, 10.08, 10.09, 10.09, 10.11, 10.14, 10.13],
    'Conductivity': [563, 561, 562, 561, 563, 560, 564, 564, 564, 565],
    'RES (Ohms.cm)': [2053, 2061, 2057, 2066, 2057, 2070, 2053, 2057, 2057, 2053],
    'TDS (mg/L)': [365, 364, 365, 364, 365, 364, 366, 366, 366, 367],
    'SAL (ppt)': [0.24] * 10,
    'SSG (st)': [0] * 10,
    'NH3': [0.01] * 10,
    'cDOM': [8.9, 8.9, 9.1, 9, 7.9, 8.7, 9.2, 8.7, 8.6, 8.9],
    'Ammonium': [0.13] * 9 + [0.12],
    'DateTime': pd.to_datetime(['2024-07-16 01:07:00', '2024-07-16 01:16:04', '2024-07-16 01:31:05', '2024-07-16 01:46:06', '2024-07-16 02:01:08', '2024-07-16 02:16:08', '2024-07-16 02:31:09', '2024-07-16 02:46:10', '2024-07-16 03:01:11', '2024-07-16 03:16:12'], utc=True),
    'DateTime15': pd.to_datetime(['2024-07-16 01:06:40', '2024-07-16 01:15:00', '2024-07-16 01:23:20', '2024-07-16 01:31:40', '2024-07-16 02:00:00', '2024-07-16 02:15:00', '2024-07-16 02:30:00', '2024-07-16 02:45:00', '2024-07-16 03:00:00', '2024-07-16 03:15:00'], utc=True)
})

# Define df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': pd.to_datetime(['2024-07-16 02:00:00.055', '2024-07-16 03:00:00.060', '2024-07-16 04:00:00.065', '2024-07-16 05:00:00.070', '2024-07-16 06:00:00.075', '2024-07-16 07:00:00.080', '2024-07-16 08:00:00.085', '2024-07-16 09:00:00.090', '2024-07-16 10:00:00.095', '2024-07-16 11:00:00.100'], utc=True),
    'Hourly_Rainfall_mm': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 1.4, 1.1],
    'DateTime15': pd.to_datetime(['2024-07-16 02:00:00.055', '2024-07-16 03:00:00.060', '2024-07-16 04:00:00.065', '2024-07-16 05:00:00.070', '2024-07-16 06:00:00.075', '2024-07-16 07:00:00.080', '2024-07-16 08:00:00.085', '2024-07-16 09:00:00.090', '2024-07-16 10:00:00.095', '2024-07-16 11:00:00.100'], utc=True)
})

# Round DateTime15 to the nearest hour to ensure exact matches
df1['DateTime15'] = df1['DateTime15'].dt.round('H')
df2['DateTime15'] = df2['DateTime15'].dt.round('H')

# Merge the dataframes
JoinedDF = pd.merge(df1, df2[['DateTime15', 'Hourly_Rainfall_mm']], on='DateTime15', how='left')

# Print the merged dataframe
print(JoinedDF)



  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/lQu0uee9.png


I'm using R and this code isn't working for me

okay, I convert this code to R with chatgpt, can you check it? # Round DateTime15 to the nearest hour to ensure exact matches
df1 <- df1 %>%
mutate(DateTime15 = as.POSIXct(format(DateTime15, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"), tz = "UTC"))
df2 <- df2 %>%
mutate(DateTime15 = as.POSIXct(format(DateTime15, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"), tz = "UTC"))
Merge the dataframes
JoinedDF <- df1 %>%
left_join(df2 %>% select(DateTime15, Hourly_Rainfall_mm), by = "DateTime15")
Print the merged dataframe
print(JoinedDF)
